# gtk2hs - Getting back a ListStore from a TreeView

Tags: haskell, treeview, gtk2hs, treemodel

I have a handle to a `TreeView` that happens to have a `ListStore` as its model. What I want to do is get back a handle to that `ListStore` from my handle to the `TreeView`.

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/147), the `treeViewGetModel` getter returns a generic `TreeModel` rather than an instance of `TreeModelClass` such as, in particular here, a `ListStore`. I am not aware of any cast function from `TreeModel` to `ListStore` either...

I also do **not** want to do [this](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.haskell.gtk2hs/2008-06/msg00005.html) (that is, just keep a handle to the model when I define it and pass it through to where I want to use it).

Is anybody aware of a good solution to that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that the tree view may have a different model. A function `TreeView a -> ListStore a` would be partial (not defined for treeviews with different models), and so unsafe to use.

This issue has been raised a number of times, on [gtk2hs's trac](http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1210) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183600/how-can-i-access-a-liststore-gtkbuilder). Proposed solutions are always similar to what you mentioned and want to avoid.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think something along the following lines would implement an unsafe casting:

```
unsafeCastToListStore :: TreeView a -> ListStore a
unsafeCastToListStore = 
  unsafeCastGObject . toGObject . treeViewGetModel
```

You could use the functions for [`GObject`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.13.2.2/docs/System-Glib-GObject.html) in the glib library to determine whether the model is indeed a `ListStore` and make the casting safe, ie. retuning `Maybe (ListStore a)`.

In particular, I'd suggest looking at `isA ::  GObjectClass o => o -> GType -> Bool`. Sadly, you might have to use use the C function `gtk_list_store_get_type` via the FFI if no other function can give you a `GType` for a `ListStore`.

Alternatively, if you can compile and bind your own fork of gtk2hs, you might be able to just re-export the internal functions/modules that gtk exports but gtk2hs doesn't (if this is for a closed-source project or for internal use), although that will incur in an extra maintenance cost.